# Difference in meaning: 多了 vs 极了

Tags: grammar, usage

I don't grasp the difference between 极了 and 多了. In what context are both to be used? Is 极了 a sort of superlative compared to 多了 ?
All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

极 means "extreme", such as 北极(north pole), 南极(south pole), 极端(extreme - nothing if not).

多 means  "much", "more", "many", "numerous",....

极了 - 好极了(extremely good), 棒极了(extremely good), 他長的難看极了([Direct translation]- His face is extremely difficult to look at. [Practical meaning] - He's so ugly.)

多了 - 好多了(getting much better), 難多了(more difficult or much difficult), 太多了(too much, or too many), note 太 can be omitted and the meaning stays the same - 你給多了(you gave too much, or too many), but 太 emphasis the act with mild complain -你給太多了!

Comment: When 多 is placed before the adjective, it can mean "so/how much something something is": 他多聰明 'how smart he is'; 多好 'how go it is'; 這個考試有多難 'how much the test is difficult'.

Answer (score 5):

“极了” is like "extremely", and usually used when you would state your opinion.

For example, you try on a new tux, and others said:

> You look fantastic in this tux =
> 你穿西装的样子真是**棒极了**

“多了” its level is lower than “极了”, and usually indicates some sort of change or comparison.

> You look better in this tux (maybe look awful in the previous one) =
> 你穿这件西装的样子看起来**好多了**

Hope this helps